# Wordpress 3.0 Multisite - Child sites and backends appearing blank

Tags: multisite, url-rewriting, redirect, urls

I've just installed wordpress on our Rackspace server - I've set wordpress up for Multisite as I have done many times before.

The main wordpress site at the root functions fine - however when I add a new site and click on either 'backend' or 'visit' I get 'page not found'.

Pages in the main site seem to work fine with the default permalink settings but not custom such as /%category%/%postname%/

I think this must be a server issue but am a bit stumped.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Do you have an htaccess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah the server is not reading the htaccess file properly.

may need 
AllowOverride FileInfo Options
in the httpd.conf file for that vhost.

Comment: Thanks very much, I posted a ticket with rackspace and that's exactly what they did. Had figured it was to do with the htaccess just wasn't aware of the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the subdomain option?

If so, I had this same issue with Rackspace using their cloud servers. If you have your own server with them, you will need to have them setup a virtual host entry for your new site.

Or you can do it if you are comfortable with ssh. If not have them do it.

You can create a new file (name it domain.conf) in the conf.d folder (location on server /etc/httpd/conf.d). The entry will look like this:

```
#<VirtualHost *:8080>
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /home/yourwordpressfolder
ServerName Your domain name for new site
<Directory "/home/yourwordpressfolder">
allow from all
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
Options +Includes -Indexes
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```